# Invalid parameter - c# Excel Interop Series.Points()

Tags: c#, excel, charts, office-interop

I have been trying to figure this one out for a while, but can't seem to get anywhere.  I am simply trying to change the color of the last column in an Excel column chart (e.g. first 3 columns blue, last column orange) using C#. I have scoured many forums and Interop class definitions to no avail.

Here is the code:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Series series1 = (Series)xlChart.SeriesCollection(2);
series1.Interior.Color = newColorList[0];

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Point point1 = (Point)series1.Points(4); //this line throws an exception
point1.Interior.Color = newColorList[7];
```

The third line throws an "Invalid Parameter" exception, and despite my searches I cannot figure out how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated, especially if I should go a different route to change the color of that last column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you used the debugger..? also do you need to create a new instance of `Point` ...

Comment: can you use series1.Points(4).Interior.Color = newColorList[7] or xlChart.SeriesCollection(2).Points(4).Interior.Color = newColorList[7]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Points index is from 1. 
And are you sure you have a 4th point in your chart?
I used

```
((Excel.Point)((Excel.Series)expchart.Chart.SeriesCollection(iseries)).Points(ipoint)).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(160, 160, 160).ToArgb();
```

and it works.

Comment: That's a painful one-liner. Break across 2-3 lines?

Comment: that's almost the same as your original code.
but i'm using 
point1.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 0).ToArgb();
instead.
and i was getting the same error because the point doesn't exist.
maybe you should make sure the 4th point of the series does exist.

Comment: Thanks Nathan! I have no idea how to make the code appear in one line.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  I tried your approach, and much like mine, it compiled just fine, but throws an "Invalid Parameter" error when it tries to access Points(4).  In this case, there are 8 points, so I knew it was valid... until I realized that in fact, I was trying to set the color of the points _just_ before I actually set the values of said points. Thank you for your help, my apologies for a "less-than-smart" question.